# How to check if an URL can be reached

Tags: url, http-status-code-301

I want to ckeck if an URL can be reached or not, otherwise I print an error message to the user.

Here is my code

```
    URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080/booksManager");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    System.out.println(connection.getResponseMessage());
```

This code throws an error and doesn't print anything on the console.
[error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDTwN.png)

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: I put the screen on the bottom of the post ?